# Vertically Align Image and Text Inside a Div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I would like to position the image and the navigation links so that they are vertically aligned with the HeadContainer and each other.

**HTML**

```
<header>
<div id="HeadContainer">
  <img src="favicon.png" id="title"/>
  <nav>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>About</p>
    <p>Portfolio</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#HeadContainer {
width:70%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}

header {
height: 60px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav p {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#title {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
}
```

At the moment they are not aligned. How would I align the paragraph tags in the nav with the image?

Comment: There's several ways to vertically align this set. Roko answer isn't really one of them, but relies on a rather fortuitous default top margin for ul elements, which could be more or less replicated by setting the p elements to `display:inline-block`. In general though, inline elements align vertically *in the flow* with *each other* on the same line. Floating elements removes them from the flow, so they can't vertically align naturally and you're reduced to nudging them into position manually with padding-top, margin-top, top etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that inside a navigation you'll hardly have `<p>` elements. I don't see any reason Google also. So go with: http://jsbin.com/melag/2/edit

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
    float: right;
}
nav ul{
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: OP, as for aligning your logo image vertically. In your stylesheet, add 'position:relative;top:10x' to '#title'.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been bugging me for days

Answer (score 0):

Roko's answer is the tried and true method.  I recommend it too.  I want to point out that, in HTML 5, the `<nav>` tag is intended to replace a modified unordered list for navigation menus.

[W3 Schools `<nav>` tag page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I'm using the <nav> tag wrong? I thought I was using it right

Comment: You're using it just fine.  The way you have implemented it is the 'most popular' way of creating navigation menus.  The newer HTML5 specification, however, recommends using the new `<nav>` tag instead of the unordered list.  Basically, it is the official 'unordered list as navigation sections' tag.